# css media querie do not work on browse resizing

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, responsive

Many questions on this but.. when I use this css code. It works on the devices and not when I resize the browser.. But if I change my css to "min-width" instead of "min-device-width" does not work at all... neither at my browser nor my phone device.. Any thoughts? Thanks

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width:1000px) {
.footericons {margin-left: 37%;}
.logo img {margin-top:-15px; width: 120px;margin-left:-55px;}
.welcome {margin-top:-20px;}
```

}

Comment: Seems to fire ok for me https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/JyPmoJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need putting only just "@media screen", also just use min-width and max-width...

```
@media screen and(min-width: 768px) and (max-width:1000px)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. If it doesn't, show us the rest of the CSS or SCSS please.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .footericons {
        margin-left: 37%;
    }
    .logo img {
        margin-top:-15px; 
        width: 120px;
        margin-left:-55px;
    }
    .welcome {
        margin-top:-20px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using **min-device-width** and **max-device-width** you check not by resizing browser window but your browser developer tool.

1. For Chrome it is **Device Toolbar**, shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
2. For Firefox it is **Responsive Design Mode**, shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

Change your queries to use **min-width** & **max-width** and it will then work with browser resize and also with developer tools (Device Toolbar, Responsive Design Mode).

You can check this tutorial this - [CSS Media Queries](http://www.yogihosting.com/css-media-queries-for-responsive-web-design/) tutorial for creating a responsive website design.